# How to use a relative path of a File in C#

Tags: c#, relative-path

I am making a launcher that will open other programs.
The programs will be in the same folder or in a sub-folders of the launcher.
Their full paths are unknown to me because user chooses where to save them.
It may be disc C, D, E, D/folder/newfoler54/sdfsdfsdf/program.exe, etc.
Show how to use relative paths for this purpose

Comment: Relative paths should just work. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Relative to what? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm

Comment: I tried Process.Start("..\\Game1.exe");
However I always get an error that file was not found.

Comment: please stick to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , because as it is your question is not sufficient for us to give any adequate answer.

Comment: @Devo0123 "..\\Game1.exe" is in the folder above the current directory of launcher which is by default the directory of the launcher exe.

Comment: @Devo0123 ".\\Game.exe" or just "Game.exe" to run the Game.exe in the current directory

Comment: @Fab Thanks I tried both methods but the file still can't be found

Comment: @Devo0123 try System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to know where you are located.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which is not necessarily the directory where your Launcher is installed.

You can use:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "SomeFile.dat")
```

to get a path relative to the directory that contains your Launcher.

Comment: What is somefile.dat?

Comment: The statement is underlined with red dots

Comment: @Devo0123 - FYI there is something called "Error List Window" that will give you a message why your statement is underlined with red dots - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window

Comment: @RandRandom thanks. In VS location is where the project is + debug folder. However a published project that is visually on a disc E next inside a folder with my game- the project is for some reason located in APPDATA. I don't know why. Is this a windows forms/.net thing? How can I produce an exe on my program and just have it whereever I want. It seems that I am having some kind of OneClick stuff not sure what it is

Comment: @Devo0123 - yes, that sounds like a OneClick installer, when you published your project - if you don't need an installer, you can simply zip the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder and share that zip - this has the "disadvantage" that no pre-request will be installed, for example .net framework or other libraries your project may need

Answer (score 0):

Your launcher has its own path:

```
var launcherFullName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var launcherPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executeableFullName);
```

Then you combine launcher's path and relative paths of other programs:

```
var absolutePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(launcherPath, relativePath);
Process.Start(abosolutePath);
```

Comment: Visual studio giving error when writing this statements because of var.

Comment: @Devo0123 The `var` keyword was introduces in C# 3.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) in 2007. You can change it to `string`.

Comment: Thanks. What is executableFullName? Should I put a "Game.exe" inside it? Also the most important: where to get the relativePath?

Comment: I put a relativePath as ".//Game.exe" but the error says that the file still can't be found

Comment: I wrote 
`string launcherFullName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            string launcherPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("WindowsFormsApp1.exe");
            MessageBox.Show(launcherPath);`

Message box shows nothing

Comment: `"WindowsFormsApp1.exe"` hasn't the path. It would be something like `"C:\Projects\MyProject\WindowsFormsApp1.exe"`, then pass would be `"C:\Projects\MyProject"`.

Comment: Yes but this way I can just tell it launch the full path. The problem is that I don't know the full path on the user's pc

Comment: Yes but this way I can just tell it launch the full path. The problem is that I don't know the full path on the user's pc